# Bootstrap Datepicker error with CSS (Not loading??)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, pug

I'm working on a project using the bootstrap datepicker but i'm having some problems. The date picker is showing up but its behind the modal. And based on looking at it the CSS isn't loading properly (I tried to set the z-index to 100000 and I can just tell the styling is not applying. Here is my code. Is there anything obvious that i'm just missing? I attached a picture below as well.

The textbox code (Written in Jade)

```
input#pickupdate.form-control.datepicker(type='text', required='true', placeholder='Return Date')
```

and in CSS I'm identifying it with .datepicker this should work right?? i.e -

```
.datepicker {
  padding: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: relative;
  direction: ltr;

  z-index: 1000000;
}
```

Furthermore within the HTML I'm running a script

```
script(type='text/javascript')
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.datepicker').datepicker();
        })
```

I know the css file is being loaded and the bootstrap datepicker files are being loaded properly based on the error console.

Link to how it is currently working:  http://postimg.org/image/rofg2ft35/ (Notice the dates above the modal but not proper formating acording to how it should work image)

How it should work: http://postimg.org/image/i7zjxjyc9/

Sorry if this is an easy question, just learning web development now and have been stuck on this for over a day.  Thanks!

Edit: added the fix Kiee suggested

Comment: Have you found a solution? cause i got the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Try adding: `position:relative` to `.datepicker` z-index has no effect on static elements.

Comment: Awesome, that helped a little bit. New Image: http://postimg.org/image/rofg2ft35/

Still isnt displaying entirely properly. Now i'm even more confused as the CSS is somewhat working..

Comment: Add background-color:#fff

Comment: That did not make a change. There is a lot of CSS code below the snippet that was part of the datepicker download and the background color was already set in the aforementioned code.

Comment: If you could post a jsfiddle I can further help you. Don't know bootstrap off the top of my head.